# How to apply function to entire dataset in R

Tags: r, function

```
home_last3 = function(team,game){
g1 = filter(g, Team == team & Game > game)
g1 = head(g1, n=3)
return(sum(g1$goals))
}

print(home_last3("Arsenal","5"))
[1] 11
```

So I have this function above. The idea is that in my dataset of all Premier League matches, I want to know how many goals the home team scored in their previous 3 matches. That dataframe g has all the games and goals scored for each team listed.

So my function does exactly what I want it to when I plug stuff in manually.

However, I want to apply this function to a new column (Home_Last_3) in my original dataset, where for any given match it can look at the name of the home team (col = "HomeTeam") and the number of the game (col="Game") and spit out that number.

However, when I inputed this:

```
df$Home_Last_3 = home_last3(df$HomeTeam,df$Game)
```

It just spit back zeros in all columns.

I think it has something to do with using as.data.frame, or sapply (but sapply got mad at me for having that second argument in there).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) -- since your function is based on a specific dataset, can you provide your data? There are also some inconsistencies in your code -- are you trying to target the variable `Team` or `HomeTeam`? Is your dataset called `df` or `g`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `mapply` which is a multivariate version of `sapply`.  If I understand your function correctly this should work:

```
df$Home_Last_3 = mapply(FUN=home_last3, df$HomeTeam, df$Game)
```